# Uncaught TypeError: lineTotal is not a function When using <form> tag / JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```js
var renumber = 0;

function calculateDueAmount() {
  var tblRows = document.getElementById("addItems").getElementsByTagName("tr");
  let total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < tblRows.length; i++) {
    let lineTotal = tblRows[i]
      .getElementsByTagName("td")[4]
      .getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    total += Number(lineTotal);
  }
  document.getElementById("amountDue").innerText = total.toFixed(2);
}

function addItem() {
  renumber++;
  var html = "<tr>";
  html += "<td id='itemNum'>" + renumber + "</td>";
  html += "<td><input name='itemName[]'></td>";

  html +=
    "<td><span class='currency'>$</span><input  onblur='lineTotal(this);' value='0' name='amount[]'></td>";
  html +=
    "<td><input  onblur='lineTotal(this);' value='0' name='qty[]'></td>";
  html +=
    "<td><span class='currency'>$</span><input onblur='lineTotal(this);' value='0' name='lineTotal[]'></td>";
  html +=
    "<td><button type='button' id='remove_button' onclick='removeItem(this);'> X </button></td>";
  html += "</tr>";
  document.getElementById("addItems").insertRow().innerHTML = html;
}

function removeItem(elem) {
  let rowToDelete = elem.parentElement.parentElement;
  let rowNumber = rowToDelete.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerText;
  document.getElementById("addItems").deleteRow(rowNumber - 1);
  let tblRows = document.getElementById("addItems").getElementsByTagName("tr");
  let j = 0;
  for (; j < tblRows.length; j++) {
    tblRows[j].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerText = j + 1;
  }
  calculateDueAmount();
  renumber = j;
}

function lineTotal(elem) {
  var mainRow = elem.parentElement.parentElement;
  var amt = mainRow
    .getElementsByTagName("td")[2]
    .getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  var qty = mainRow
    .getElementsByTagName("td")[3]
    .getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  var total = mainRow
    .getElementsByTagName("td")[4]
    .getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  var myResult = Number(amt) * Number(qty);
  total.value = myResult;
  calculateDueAmount();
}
```

```html
<div class="home-section">
  <div class="sign-up-box">
    <h1>Payment details</h1>

    <div class="signup-container">
      <label>Service Ticket Number : </label>
      <br />

      <form action="" method="post">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>

            <th>Amount per unit</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Line Total</th>
          </tr>

          <tbody id="addItems"></tbody>
        </table>

        <p>
          <button type="button" onclick="addItem();">Add Item</button>
        </p>

        <p>
          Amount Due: $<span id="amountDue">0.00</span>
          <script src="includes/javascript.js"></script>
        </p>

        <p>
          <input id="invoice_submit" type="submit" name="submit" />
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This my first time posting. Code is working perfectly. It is able to run its function like add rows, auto calculate amount and qty column and display it on the linetotal column.

The only problem here is that when I add `<form>` tag into the the code, the auto calculation stops working because of this error

> Uncaught TypeError: lineTotal is not a function

where is doesn't recognise lineTotal as a function.
I have already tried console.log(lineTotal) and it displayed the lineTotal function.

Comment: I think you're running into an issue where id'd elements are assigned to global variables. Try removing the `id` attributes from your added `<input>` elements. They shouldn't be duplicated anyway

Comment: I followed your instruction and removed the id attributes in the additem() function. The code is now working perfectly with the forms tag. Thx for the help.